# Problemas em implementar a lib ng2-img-max!

Tags: angular

Eu instalei o ng2-img-max com o objetivo de redimensionar imagens. Eu quero que cada imagem enviada seja redimensionada para uma largura e comprimento pré-definidos. Eu vejo que a maioria das pessoas usam ng2-img-max ao desenvolver com angular 2/4. Eu tentei usar com essa lib e depois enfrentei o seguinte erro:

`Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for Ng2PicaService`

Esse erro informa que precisa ser colocado o nome do serviço nos providers, o problema é que no meu projeto não criei nenhum serviço com esse nome, estou me guiando por esse tutorial abaixo;

[Resizing Images in the Browser in Angular With ng2-img-max](https://alligator.io/angular/resizing-images-in-browser-ng2-img-max/)

Eu criei um modulo para armazenar todos os serviços referente a implementação do redimensionador de imagens como você pode ver abaixo;

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ImgMaxPXSizeService } from './img-maxpx-size.service';
import { ImgMaxSizeService } from './img-max-size.service';
import { Ng2ImgMaxService } from './ng2-img-max.service';
import { ImgExifService } from './img-exif.service';
import { Ng2PicaService } from '../../../node_modules/ng2-pica';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [],
  providers: [
    ImgMaxPXSizeService,
    ImgExifService,
    ImgMaxSizeService,
    Ng2ImgMaxService
]
})
export class ImgMaxModule { }

//https://github.com/bergben/ng2-img-max
```

E o modulo eu publiquei no arquivo **app.module.ts**

como podem ver abaixo;

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule,
    SharedModule,
    RestaurantModule,
    AdminModule,
    ImgMaxModule,// >>>>>>> modulo de imagens
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Como eu poderia contornar esse problema?

Eu acho que somente pessoas que já mexeram com essa lib terá condições de me ajuda.

Esse é meu projeto completo no repositório **github**.

[REPOSITÓRIO](https://github.com/wladyband/angular-sistema-vendas/tree/master/src/app/img-max)

Comment: tenta importar o ImgMaxModule no modulo que vc declara seu componente

Comment: @EduardoVargas eu acho que esse não é o problema, o problema é o arquivo `Ng2PicaService`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está declarando os providers porém não importou o módulo `Ng2ImgMaxModule` como manda a documentação do link que você publicou.

```
import { Ng2ImgMaxModule } from 'ng2-img-max';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    // ...
    Ng2ImgMaxModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Tente importar este módulo dentro do seu `ImgMaxModule`.

Comment: Pego, muito obrigado nossa que legal, já estava desistindo.. hahahahaha

Comment: Hahaha acontece...